# Android window setFlags

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-windowmanager

I tried to call `setflags` for a window in Android. I have an activity and several fragments. I want one of the fragments to have a different configuration. So I `setflags` in onCreate function for this fragment. But this doesn't work. I think the system need to reload the configuration for the window.

How can I do this?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
}
```